# Jenkins hash in C, keys with size that is not multiple of 4 and address sanitizer

Tags: c, dpdk, address-sanitizer

In the project I'm currently working on (in C), we're currently
keeping a hash table of some opaque objects. We're using the DPDK for
I/O in our app (version 16.07.2, unfortunately), and we're using the
rte_hash code for hashing our object. Trouble is, the objects we want
to hash have weird, non-rounded sizes like say 83 (or 18 as in the
example below), and address sanitizer complains about
heap-buffer-overflow (on read) - trying to read bytes after the end of
the region:

```
==4926==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60300007a9c0 at pc 0x000000451573 bp 0x7fff69175040 sp 0x7fff69175030
READ of size 4 at 0x60300007a9c0 thread T10ESC[1mESC[0m
#0 0x451572 in __rte_jhash_2hashes /path/to/../dpdk/usr/include/dpdk/rte_jhash.h:155
#1 0x452bb6 in rte_jhash_2hashes /path/to/../dpdk/usr/include/dpdk/rte_jhash.h:266
#2 0x452c75 in rte_jhash /path/to/../dpdk/usr/include/dpdk/rte_jhash.h:309

0x60300007a9c2 is located 0 bytes to the right of 18-byte region [0x60300007a9b0,0x603
```

00007a9c2)

As far as I can tell, the problem is here in rte_jhash.h (see here for
code in the latest DPDK, it's unchanged as far as I can tell:
http://dpdk.org/doc/api/rte__jhash_8h_source.html):

```
    case 6:
        b += k[1] & LOWER16b_MASK; a += k[0]; break;
```

The code reads k[1] as a uint32_t, and then ANDs the value so that the
last 2 bytes are discarded. As far as I can tell, address sanitizer
complains about the uint32_t read, when only the first 2 bytes are
actually marked as readable. This makes sense, but the rte_hash code
boasts that it can use keys of any size. So my question is - is this
problem theoretical only? Or would it be possible to cause a crash with
this, maybe with a weird sized object that happens to be at the end of
a page? We're running on x86-64.

A few months ago, a change in the DPDK added something in the comments about this (see http://dpdk.org/browse/dpdk/commit/lib/librte_hash?id=0c57f40e66c8c29c6c92a7b0dec46fcef5584941), but I would've expected the wording to be more harsh if a crash was possible.

UPDATE: sample code to reproduce the warning. Compile with:

```
gcc -o jhash_malloc  -Wall -g -fsanitize=address -I /path/to/dpdk/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/ jhash_malloc.c
```

And the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <rte_jhash.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    size_t strSize = 13;
    char *str = malloc(strSize);
    memset(str, 'g', strSize);
    uint32_t hval = rte_jhash(str, strSize, 0);
    printf("Hash of %s (size %zu) is %u\n", str, strSize, hval);

    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE2: And the output:

```
==27276==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000effc at pc 0x000000401315 bp 0x7ffdea936f80 sp 0x7ffdea936f70
READ of size 4 at 0x60200000effc thread T0
#0 0x401314 in __rte_jhash_2hashes /home/stefan/src/dpdk-17.08/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_jhash.h:165
#1 0x402771 in rte_jhash_2hashes /home/stefan/src/dpdk-17.08/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_jhash.h:266
#2 0x402830 in rte_jhash /home/stefan/src/dpdk-17.08/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_jhash.h:309
#3 0x4028e7 in main /home/stefan/src/test/misc/jhash_malloc.c:12
#4 0x7f470cb1f82f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
#5 0x400978 in _start (/home/stefan/src/test/misc/jhash_malloc+0x400978)

0x60200000effd is located 0 bytes to the right of 13-byte region [0x60200000eff0,0x60200000effd)
```

UPDATE3: the original Jenkins hash code seems to be this: http://burtleburtle.net/bob/c/lookup3.c. There is an interesting comment in the source that suggests the asan / valgrind warning can be ignored:

```
 * "k[2]&0xffffff" actually reads beyond the end of the string, but
 * then masks off the part it's not allowed to read.  Because the
 * string is aligned, the masked-off tail is in the same word as the
 * rest of the string.  Every machine with memory protection I've seen
 * does it on word boundaries, so is OK with this.  But VALGRIND will
 * still catch it and complain.  The masking trick does make the hash
 * noticably faster for short strings (like English words).
```

Of course, if you want to hash parts of a larger object that's malloc-ed, you could still be in trouble.

Comment: I think you're going to need to show an MCVE ([MCVE]) based on your code that reproduces the warning.  We can't guess what you're doing.

Comment: I think I've done my best to explain the issue, and since this is a situation that might or might not hit a corner case, I don't think the code helps that much. I've posted some sample code, though.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, if the key you are passing to `rte_jhash()` is happened to be at the end of the page and the next page if not readable, the app will crash. The commit you are referring to is basically fixing it, but in the documentation, not in the code.

The solution would be either to:

1. make sure all the keys in your code are aligned and padded to the 4 bytes; (also see notes below)
2. OR fix the key length in your code to be multiply of 4;
3. OR copy-paste `rte_jhash()` in your project and fix it and later send the fix to the DPDK mailing list.

Note 1: usually structures in C are already aligned and padded to the largest primitive data type of a structure. So this explicit padding should not cause any performance/memory issues, unless the structure is packed.

Note 2: if the keys are manages by DPDK library (i.e. you use DPDK Cuckoo Hash library), the storage for the keys will be aligned and padded internally, so there is nothing to be worried about.

Overall, if your keys are managed externally (i.e. by another process, or you receive those from network etc), it might be a real issue. Otherwise, there are quite easy ways to fix those...

Comment: We basically receive these data types from a library we use, and they can be either URLs or opaque structures; we make copies of those for our use. Both have arbitrary size, but yes, we can round up the amount we allocate for them to a multiple of 4. I'm also inclined to think that that is necessary, but when could this blow up? If the data happens to be at the end of a page, like the DPDK comment suggests?

Comment: @fencekicker yes, if the 18-byte key is at the very end of an allocated page. It is very unlikely, since all the allocations are by default aligned, so the C structures are aligned and padded. But in some rare circumstances (i.e. the 18-byte key is starting at unaligned address, not multiple of 4) it might be a case. But you better fix this anyway, since unaligned memory access is slow.